# What is meaning of precision in this line?

Tags: terminology, measurements, error-analysis

Quote: "This agrees with the relativistic predictions to a precision of about 1.6%". This is the statement, but what does it exactly mean?
Does it mean that 'The Theory predicts 100 units and experiments found 1.6 units.
OR
Does it means that 'Ths theory predicts 100 units and experiments found
100-1.6=98.4?

Which of the above explanation is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the theoretical prediction is $100$, then the measured value lies between $100-1.6$ and $100+1.6$.

(If it were measured as $1.6$ the theory predicting $100$ isn't very good, is it?)

Comment: Thanks buddy... 